# Why is my rectangle position off from my emoji position?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show a rounded rectangle over an emoji which im dragging into the screen but when i select it, it always puts the rounded rectangle off... I've tried everything but I can't figure it out why it puts it so wrong

```
@ViewBuilder
    private func documentContents(in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        AsyncImage(url: document.backround).position(Emoji.Position.zero.in(geometry))
        ForEach(document.emojis) { emoji in
            var unselected = false
            Group {
                Text(emoji.string)
                    .font(emoji.font)
                    .position(emoji.position.in(geometry))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if chosenEmojis.contains(emoji.id){
                            deselectEmoji(emoji)
                            unselected = true
                        }
                        if !unselected {
                            chooseEmoji(emoji)
                        }
                        print(chosenEmojis)
                    }
                if chosenEmojis.contains(emoji.id) {
                    selectEmoji(emoji, in: geometry)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
@ViewBuilder
    func selectEmoji(_ emoji: Emoji, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        
        let emojiPoisition = emoji.position.in(geometry)
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
            .position(emojiPoisition)
            .frame(width: paletteEmojisSize / zoom, height: paletteEmojisSize / zoom)
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .onAppear {
                print(emojiPoisition)
            }
    }
extension EmojiArt.Emoji.Position {
    func `in` (_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        let centre = geometry.frame(in: .local).center
        return CGPoint(x: centre.x + CGFloat(x), y: centre.y - CGFloat(y))
    }
```